# Calling stored proc from bash script, ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Tags: python, linux, oracle, bash

I'm attempting to call a stored procedure from a bash script, from a python script. The script calling works fine, there's no issue there. The issue is with the parameter for the `PRIMARY_KEYS` field. With a single `PK` it works fine, but for multiple `PK` ie, `A, B, C`, I get the oracle error: `ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated`

Python:

```
...
cmd = 'sh pkg_mypkg.sh \'%s\' \'%s\' my_sp_which_adds_a_primary_key \'%s\'' % db_login_str db_table primary_keys
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=TRUE)
...
```

Bash:

```
DB_LOGIN_STR=$1
DB_TABLE=$2
FUNC_TO_EXEC=$3
PRIMARY_KEYS=$4

...

function my_sp_which_adds_a_primary_key() {
  SP_RES=`sqlplus -silent $1 <<-EOM
  ...
  BEGIN
    pkg_mypkg.my_sp_which_adds_a_primary_key($2, $3);
  END;
  ...
  EOM`
  echo $SP_RES
}

...

function main() {
  case $FUNC_TO_EXEC in
     "my_sp_which_adds_a_primary_key")
        my_sp_which_adds_a_primary_key(DB_LOGIN_STR, DB_TABLE, PRIMARY_KEYS);;
  esac
}

main
```

SP:

```
procedure my_sp_which_adds_a_primary_key(db_table in varchar2, primary_keys in varchar2)
is
begin
 execute immediate 'alter table ' || db_table || ' add constraint ' || db_table || '_PK primary_key (' || primary_keys || ') parallel 8';  
end my_sp_which_adds_a_primary_key;
```

As a disclaimer, I've tested this function directly within the PLSQL UI interface, in a test window, and it works fine w/ multiple `PKs`. There's a problem with how I am passing to the stored proc when executed within Bash, which I cannot figure out. I've tried combinations of `\'\'%s\'\'`, `\'%s\'`, `\'\"%s\"`, `"%s"`, ... Not sure what the right format is.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try is to call the command from your Python code like this:

```
cmd = ["pkg_mypkg.sh", db_login_str, db_table, "my_sp_which_adds_a_primary_key", primary_keys]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) (my emphasis):

> *args* should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in *args* if *args* is a sequence. If *args* is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, **it is recommended to pass *args* as a sequence**.

Also, I've removed `shell=TRUE` as well as the call to `sh`, as they can both cause complications and, in the case of the former, [security risks](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). You should instead simply ensure that `pkg_mypkg.sh` is executable with a proper shebang. The documentation again:

> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. If *args* is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If *args* is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

---

Without seeing the full shell script it's hard to say what problems there might be, though you are calling variables without a preceding `$`, and I'd recommend putting the SP text into a file rather than rely on a construct like heredoc inside backticks. http://shellcheck.net/ can be helpful to spot errors and non-standard usage.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'm going to test them out shortly. For now, I've removed the whitespaces within my `PRIMARY_KEY` var so `A, B, C` became `A,B,C` and that seems to have worked.
Some wonky thing was happening where, `A, B, C` became just `A,`.